# Static blocks on home page CE 1.9 RWD Demo Theme

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, rwd-theme, cms-block

I was wondering how you would create the static blocks on the home page in the RWD Madison Island theme, the three below the sliding banner?  Can they be created just using the static blocks and widget GUI or do you need to enter code?  Many thanks for any suggestions. I thought this would be a trivial issue.

Answer (score 1):

`Madison Island` Home page is a CMS page which is using by Magento's latest versions (ie `version >= 1.9`). But it is a CMS Page itself. So you can use different methods to include a static block inside this Home Page.

In your case, since you want your static block just below the banner, you can either go on with either

### - Block Directive way

place below content after banner code inside content section.

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="{your_static_block_identifier}"}}
```

### - Widget Way

Magento also provide a provision to add static blocks as widget. Widget is doing the same thing as we do manually in the above step. But it is a good technique for those who are NOT technically RICH about Magento. If you dont know how to use the widget feature in cms pages, I recommend you to [go through this video](http://leveluptuts.com/tutorials/magento-community-tutorials/18-how-create-edit-and-display-static-blocks-using-widgets). Or there are lot of lot of tutorials for this. You just need to GOOGLE it.